# Heroku + CloudFlare + Apartment Redirecting to "com.br"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, cloudflare

I give Up!
I don't know what to do anymore.

A have registred a domain at registro.br ("example.com.br") and point it to my cloud flare account servers.
On cloudFlare I've set 2 CNAME : 
"www" and "example.com.br", both pointing to my heroku's app address.

And at my heroku's account I've set up the DNS to my domain  example.com.br...

I'm using the apartment GEM and locally it's perfect. My project is based on the timetracker project.

But when I deploy it to heroku it redirects to "com.br".
I've already added the "example" as excluded_subdomain.rb.
The heroku log says that can't find 'public' or 'example' Tenant and redirects to "com.br"... WTF?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this answer is for everybody that hasn´t just ".com" at the end of your domain...
You just need to put into your production.rb file this code:

```
config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 2
```

In my case I have ".com.br" at the end, so I needed to tell rails that this has length equals 2 (com and br).

Thats it